# Please recommend some great calculus reference books

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

I’m taking MIT ocw single variavle calculus now, and I found I need some books to help with studying. I know Stewart or Thomas calculus is famous for calculus. But I think it’s too huge. And that’s the reason why I have tried to take online lecture. So could you please recommend some calculus books to practice exercises? I want a books which are not huge like Stewart, have some challenge problems, not much focused on analysis. I read some people recommend books, but I think it’s more focused on analysis than calculus.

Comment: What about khan's academy or paul's notes?

Comment: http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Apostol%20-%20CALCULUS%20-%20VOLUME%201%20-%20One-Variable%20Calculus,%20with%20an%20Introduction%20to%20Linear%20Algebra.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Granville, Smith and Longley has been a classic for decades and is in the public domain.

[Elements of the differential and integral calculus](https://archive.org/details/elementsdiffere02goog)